# Can one obliviously reflect about the *initial* state in fixed-point amplitude amplification?

Tags: amplitude-amplification

It is normal to extend [fixed-point amplitude amplification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3305) to an oblivious version, i.e.,
$1 - (1-e^{i \beta})|t\rangle \langle t |  \rightarrow 1 - (1-e^{i \beta}) 1 \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0|$, and one uses an additional ancilla to apply a phase to the target state $|t\rangle$.

However typically the other reflection, $1 - (1-e^{-i\alpha}) |0\rangle \langle 0|$ is about the all-zero initial state.  But suppose you are given an unknown initial state, $|\psi_0 \rangle$.  You know you can construct a unitary $U$ that does
$$
U |\psi_0\rangle |0\rangle = \sqrt{a}|A_0\rangle |0\rangle + \sqrt{1-a}|A_1\rangle |1\rangle,
$$
and so could amplify the probability of $|A_{0}\rangle |0\rangle$ to 1, but only if you could implement $1 - (1-e^{-i\alpha})|\psi_0\rangle\langle \psi_0 | \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0|$, and you don't know how $|\psi_{0}\rangle$ came about.  Is it possible instead to construct a unitary $U'$ that will give you
$$
U' |\psi_0\rangle |0\rangle = \sqrt{a}|A_0\rangle |0\rangle + \sqrt{1-a}|A_1\rangle |1\rangle,
$$
while simultaneously only using $1 - (1-e^{-i\alpha})1\otimes |0\rangle \langle 0|$ for the initial state reflection during amplitude amplification?  It is not clear to me how one would construct a $U'$ that moves between the two bases $|A_0\rangle |0\rangle$, $|A_1\rangle |1\rangle$, and $|\psi_0\rangle |0\rangle$, $|\psi_{1}\rangle |1\rangle$, for some $|\psi_1 \rangle |1\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to combine fixed-point amplitude amplification with oblivious amplitude amplification, provided that $a$ in the definition of $U$ is independent of the input state $|\psi_0\rangle$, as discussed in [this paper by Dalzell, Yoder, and Chuang](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.012311) (cf. Section VI.B in particular). Importantly, that means oblivious amplitude amplification does not work if $U$ is non-unitary. [This paper by Guerreschi](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.99.022306) also discusses fixed-point oblivious amplitude amplification.

Comment: My question is whether one can reflect obliviously about the *initial* state.